# Given three probabilities, what is the difference between $p_1/(p_1 + p_2)$ and $p_1 + p_3/2$?

Tags: probability

Given three probabilities, what is the difference between $p_1/(p_1 + p_2)$ and $p_1 + p_3/2$?

Say we have three outcomes and thus three probabilities $p_1, p_2, p_3$. But we don't really care about $p_3$. If it happens, we'll pretend that the experiment did not take place at all, and repeat, until we get one of the first two outcomes.

But, in that case, what is the probability of the first outcome, or the second outcome, assuming we pretend the third outcomes do not exist?

Is it $p_1/(p_1 + p_2)$ and $p_2/(p_1 + p_2)$? Or is it $p_1 + p_3/2$ and $p_2 + p_3/2$?

Both these two methods give us probabilities that sum to 1, and both make intuitive sense to me.

Comment: If you're ignoring one of the events, you are essentially conditioning the other two probabilities on the occurrence of their respective events.

Comment: The $p_1 + p_3/2$ and $p_2+p_3/2$ suggestion implies that if the third event happens, then subsequently (you say you'll repeat) the chances of the other two are equal, 1/2 each. Can you see the flaw in that?